# Different Interactions specifications with gamm

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Could someone please explain how these two `gamm` from the `mgcv` package specifications differ?

I am using the Owls data and first model example from the Zuur text on Mixed Models found here: (http://www2.unil.ch/popgen/modsel/rcode/owls.R)

```
M7 <- gamm(NegPerChick~FoodTreatment +
             s(ArrivalTime,by=as.numeric(FoodTreatment=="Deprived")) +
             s(ArrivalTime,by=as.numeric(FoodTreatment=="Satiated")),
           random=list(Nest=~1),data=Owls)
```

compared to:

```
new <- gamm(NegPerChick~FoodTreatment + s(ArrivalTime, by=FoodTreatment),           
            random=list(Nest=~1),data=Owls)
```

If FoodTreatment only has two levels: `"Deprived"` and `"Satiated,"`  with smoothers applied in both cases to the interaction between each level and ArrivalTime, should these models both be equivalent?

I find that when I substitute my data but keep the model structure, I always get convergence issues with the `new` model, which makes me think that the second structure is more data intensive.

Any insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Those two calls to `gamm()` essentially specify the same model but `M7` is clearly unstable when the algorithm tries to fit the model. I currently get:

```
> gamm(NegPerChick~FoodTreatment +
+              s(ArrivalTime,by=as.numeric(FoodTreatment=="Deprived")) +
+              s(ArrivalTime,by=as.numeric(FoodTreatment=="Satiated")),
+            random=list(Nest=~1),data=Owls)
Error in MEestimate(lmeSt, grps) : 
  Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1
```

which suggests to me (although I haven't looked) that the model is over specified; indeed, `?s` says that for numeric `by`, you shouldn't include the "main effect" because there are no centring constraints applied to numeric by splines. But the problems with that model are deeper than this.

On the contrary, I see no problems with `new` and this is how I would fit this model, with only a couple of levels of the `by` variable

```
> new <- gamm(NegPerChick~FoodTreatment + s(ArrivalTime, by=FoodTreatment),           
+             random=list(Nest=~1),data=Owls)
>
```

I haven't dug into this, but I get quite different fits between `new` and fitting the model using simple random effects splines with `gam()`:

```
new2 <- gam(NegPerChick ~ FoodTreatment + s(ArrivalTime, by=FoodTreatment) +
              s(Nest, bs = "re"), data = Owls, method = "ML")

> summary(new$gam)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
NegPerChick ~ FoodTreatment + s(ArrivalTime, by = FoodTreatment)

Parametric coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)             2.0029     0.1291  15.517  < 2e-16 ***
FoodTreatmentSatiated  -0.8535     0.1205  -7.081  4.1e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                       edf Ref.df      F  p-value    
s(ArrivalTime):FoodTreatmentDeprived 7.152  7.152 11.500 6.02e-14 ***
s(ArrivalTime):FoodTreatmentSatiated 1.000  1.000  7.367  0.00684 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.165   
  Scale est. = 1.9547    n = 599
> summary(new2)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
NegPerChick ~ FoodTreatment + s(ArrivalTime, by = FoodTreatment) + 
    s(Nest, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)             2.0076     0.1301  15.428  < 2e-16 ***
FoodTreatmentSatiated  -0.8622     0.1198  -7.199 1.93e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                        edf Ref.df      F  p-value    
s(ArrivalTime):FoodTreatmentDeprived  7.258  8.266 10.210 1.06e-13 ***
s(ArrivalTime):FoodTreatmentSatiated  4.894  5.991  3.215  0.00371 ** 
s(Nest)                              18.316 26.000  2.395 7.13e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.263   Deviance explained = 30.2%
-REML =   1082  Scale est. = 1.9215    n = 599
```

Something is causing the `gamm()` model to smooth the `Satiated` spline back to a linear function, that isn't happening in the `gam()`.

Given the `by` as a factor fit is the correct way to fit the model you want, it may be that something else is causing the problem with your data.

Answer (score 0):

These models should be equivalent but the `gamm` function gives different outputs. I'll use as an example the `Hawaii` dataset from the book you have mentioned (mainly, paragraph 6.2). In the book you have:

```
BM2 = gamm(Birds ~ Rain + ID + 
          s(Time, by = as.numeric(ID == "Stilt.Oahu"))+
          s(Time, by = as.numeric(ID == "Stilt.Maui"))+
          s(Time, by = as.numeric(ID == "Coot.Oahu"))+
          s(Time, by = as.numeric(ID == "Coot.Maui")),
        corretalion = corAR1(form =~Time|ID),
        weights = varIdent(form = ~1 |ID))
```

I get an error here

```
Error in MEestimate(lmeSt, grps) : 
Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1
```

Instead I decided to use

```
BM2 <- gamm(Birds ~Rain + ID + s(Time, by = ID), 
corretalion = corAR1(form =~Time|ID), weights = varIdent(form = ~1 |ID))
```

Now, the output of `anova(BM2$gam)` differs from the output in the book. Note also that the output of `AIC(BM1$lme, BM2$lme)`, where `BM1 <- gamm(Birds ~ Rain + ID + s(Time, by = ID),weights = varIdent(form =~1|ID))` , is

```
        df      AIC
BM1$lme 17 2362.142
BM2$lme 17 2362.142
```

which should not happen and drives concerns. The outputs differ, so the models are not equivalent for the `gamm` function.